# can't popup a panel from a popup panel using fancybox

Tags: fancybox

I want to popup simple panel from a panel that was already poped up. 
I use fancybox. here is the code how I call and how I define the panel!

what can is my mistake? what should I do?

```
​<a href=​"#ctl00_MainContent_c312_ppp">​click meeeee​</a>​
<div style=​"display:​ none">​<div id=​"ctl00_MainContent_c312_ppp" style=​"background-color:​Black;​">​        
popup test</div>​ </div>​
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a custom script like:

```
$("a.fancyLink").fancybox();
```

then your anchor should have the same class in order to be bonded to fancybox like:

```
<a class="fancyLink" href=​"#ctl00_MainContent_c312_ppp">​click meeeee​</a>​
```